# Where to place "all" and "soon" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

1. Let's hope all this will soon be over so we can get home to our families.
2. Let's hope this will all be over soon so we can get home to our families.
3. Let's hope all this will be over soon so we can get home to our families.
4. Let's hope all this soon will be over so we can get home to our families.

I'm not sure about where to place "all" and "soon" in this sentence. What would be the more natural way to phrase the sentence? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences are grammatically correct.
Sentence 2 (**this will all be over soon**) is the idiomatic one in American English, in my experience, though it has a sense of finality in an "end of the world" kind of way.
Sentence 3 (**all this will be over soon**) could also work in your context.